# Python: Most common integer in a loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I'm supposed to enact the rolling of a 6 sided die and compute the average, which I have done. The second part of my assignment is to find the most common number within that loop of 1s-6s. So if 4 was the mode of the rolling of a die then the program should return or give me a value of 4. I'm speculating that I should perhaps use a list for this and record each value into the list? not quite sure. Here is my code so far:

```
import random

def rollDie(number):
    count = 0
    for x in range(0,number): 
       result = random.randint(1,6)
       print(result)
       count += result
    return count/float(number)
```

Comment: Your code does not look like Java, don't worry. One quick thing you can shorten easily is just to use `range(number)` as 0 is the default start. The function can be considerably shortened to just `return sum(random.randint(1,6) for x in range(number))/float(number)` but I'm just pointing that out for interest's sake, don't feel bad for not knowing you could do that as a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list

```
dices = [ 0,0,0,0,0,0 ]
for x in range(number):
    d = randint(1,6)
    dices[d-1] += 1
```

or a dictionnary

```
dices = { 1:0, 2:0, 3:0, 4:0, 5:0, 6:0 }    
for x in range(number):
    d = randint(1,6)
    dices[d] += 1
```